# JQuery on change events

Tags: jquery

I have this JQuery code which is working great apart from one thing:

```
//customer changed - update the contact list for the selected customer
            //get relevant customer info for IDs
            $("#ticket_customer").on('change', function() {
                var html = $.ajax({
                    url: "?getContactList=1&customer=" + $(this).val(),
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ticket_contact").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#ticket_customer").on('change', function() {
                //customer address
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "?getCustomer=1&sequence=" + $(this).val() + "",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ticket_customer_address").html(data[0].address);
                    }
                });
            });


$("#ticket_contact").on('change', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "?getCustomerByContact=1&sequence=" + $(this).val() + "",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ticket_customer").val(data[0].sequence).trigger('change');
                    }
                });
            });
```

if a customer is selected, it will generate a list of contacts for that customer and put the address into a `p` tag.

if a contact is selected, it will select the correct customer for that contact, then because the customer select element has been changed it will generate the address into the `p` tag. When this is done however, because the customer has been changed it re-generates the contact list which removes the already selected contact.

how can i stop the selected contact being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the change event for contacts generation, bind it alone to for address generation, you can write it in a function and call it whenever necessary, and this will stop triggering the contact generation call.
Change it like this:

```
/customer changed - update the contact list for the selected customer
            //get relevant customer info for IDs
            function generate_contacts(obj) {
                var html = $.ajax({
                    url: "?getContactList=1&customer=" + obj.val(),
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ticket_contact").html(data);
                        address_change($("#ticket_customer"));
                    }
                });
            }

            $('#ticket_customer').on('change',function(){
                //customer address
               generate_address($(this));
               generate_contacts($(this));
            });
function generate_address(obj){
   $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "?getCustomer=1&sequence=" + obj.val() + "",
                    data: obj.serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#ticket_customer_address").html(data[0].address);
                    }
                });
}

$("#ticket_contact").on('change', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "?getCustomerByContact=1&sequence=" + $(this).val() + "",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                          $("#ticket_customer").val(data[0].sequence);
                        generate_address($("#ticket_customer"));
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: i dont think using "this" will work in the function arguements ?